# jquery change image src and div positions onselect

Tags: jquery, css

I have a select box, I want the onchange some image that I have will change, And some other divs will change thier (css:top,right values) how I do that with Jquery?

I have this code right now (not in jquery and its not change the top,right of the other divs..)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapImage(){
        var image = document.getElementById("img");
        var dropd = document.getElementById("text");
        image.src = dropd.value;    
    };
</script>

<select id="text" onChange="swapImage()" style="width:70px;">
    <option value="images/1.jpg">1</option>
    <option value="images/2.jpg">2</option>
    <option value="images/3.png">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you try anything?If yes,Please show your code

Comment: have you tried anything? for future reference, you'll normally get a better response from users here if you try something first, then show what you've tried and why you are stuck... rather than just asking people to do your work for you from the start.

Comment: I added example of what i have now

Comment: You do have jquery right? You asked about jquery and tagged jquery but didn't use any jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your html working (you can inspect the image element to see the `src` is changing): http://jsfiddle.net/69GNC/1/

```
$("#text").on("change", function() {
    $("#img").prop("src", $(this).val());
    // you could also add something like this for your other req.:
    // $("#otherDiv").css({"top": "10px", "left": "15px" });
});
```

note: you'll want to make sure your dom is accessible when this code is reached, for that reason you could wrap it in a `$document.ready(function() { [code here] });`

Comment: thank you for replay, but it dosent work for me. wrote that code:  <script type="text/javascript">
  $document.ready(function() {
   $("#tactic").on("change", function() {
    $(#pg).css({"top": "10px", "left": "15px" });
   });
  });
 </script> and it dont do anything. Also, I want that the Div will change according to the selectd option.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details then on how you want the div to change.

Comment: Also, wasn't your first concern the image changing? You didn't even include that in your code. Can you clarify what you are doing and what is happening?

Comment: Here is an example with div moving differently depending on selected option: http://jsfiddle.net/69GNC/2/

Comment: Thank you smerny. changed some stuff ad now its work great :)

Answer (score 0):

## example HTML

```
<select id='my-select-box'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

## javascript using jQuery

```
$('#my-select-box').on('change', doStuff());

function doStuff(){
  //change an image
  //move some divs
}
```

you may also use the [.change() function](http://api.jquery.com/change/) as a shortcut if you prefer.